# Implement 2D Burgers Equation on FiPy

Tags: python, numerical-methods, fipy

It is stated [here](https://fipy.nist.narkive.com/Fw7oq89Q/non-linear-convection-term) that FiPy was not good at handling Hyperbolic PDE's. However this forum was written in 2016 so maybe things have changed a bit.

I would like to implement the 2D Burgers Equation:

$$

u_t + (u \partial_x + v \partial_y) u = -\nu * \nabla^{2} u \

v_t + (u \partial_x + v \partial_y) v = -\nu * \nabla^{2} v

$$

where $u$ and $v$ are the x and y components of that fluid flow $ U = (u, v) $.

To make my life a bit easier, I employed the chain rule to rewrite the equations as

$$

u_t + \nabla \cdot (U u) = (\nabla \cdot U) u - \nu * \nabla^{2} u \

v_t + \nabla \cdot (U v) = (\nabla \cdot U) v - \nu * \nabla^{2} v

$$

What this translates to in FiPy would be something like this:

```
u = CellVariable(name='u', mesh=m)
v = CellVariable(name='v', mesh=m)
U = CellVariable(name='U', mesh=m, value=(u, v))

eqn1 = TransientTerm(var=u) + ConvectionTerm(coeff=U, var=u) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=-nu, var=u) + # Not Sure what
eqn2 = TransientTerm(var=v) + ConvectionTerm(coeff=U, var=v) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=-nu, var=v) + # Not Sure what

burgersEq2D = eqn1 & eqn2
```

My question is: How do I finish implementing `eqn1` and `eqn2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write

```py
u = fp.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name="u")
v = fp.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name="v")
U = u.faceValue * [[1],[0]] + v.faceValue * [[0], [1]]
U.name = "U"

burgersEq2D = eqn1 & eqn2

eqn1 = (TransientTerm(var=u) + ConvectionTerm(coeff=U, var=u)
        == ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=U.divergence, var=u)
        + DiffusionTerm(coeff=nu, var=u))
eqn2 = (TransientTerm(var=v) + ConvectionTerm(coeff=U, var=v)
        == ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=U.divergence, var=v)
        + DiffusionTerm(coeff=nu, var=v))

burgersEq2D = eqn1 & eqn2
```

Writing

```py
U = CellVariable(name='U', mesh=m, value=(u, v))
```

will leave `U` with the value of the initial condition and will not update as the problem evolves, whereas the expression I wrote will update as necessary.

Also, I believe you have a sign error in the diffusion term. A negative diffusion coefficient on the right-hand side is destabilizing and is also not consistent with the [statements of Burgers' equation I've seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation).